# No redirect in apache2 VirtualHost

Tags: tomcat, apache2

I have a `tomcat:8080` behind an `apache2` proxy.
I want the proxy to redirect a specific path:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    Redirect "/test" "/test2"   
</VirtualHost>
```

(of course I executed an apache reload/restart afterwards).

But when I call `http://<ip>:8080/test`, no redirect happens.

What might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `Listen 8080` to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.